# What part-of-speech is "running" in this example?

Tags: parts-of-speech

What part-of-speech is "running" in the following example?

> - The car comes with **daytime running lights**.

Is it a noun, verb (gerung), adjective, or something else?

Comment: It functions as an adjective (as does "daytime").  Different "schools" of syntactic nomenclature will give it different names.

Comment: Yes. I agree with @HotLicks. And I would definitely hyphenate 'daylight-running'.

Comment: @HotLicks It's not an adjective: the lights are not running. They're **for** running. It's a noun-noun compound. Make that a noun-noun-noun compound for *daytime running lights*: just three nouns together and no adjective in sight.

Comment: @tchrist - Like I said, it functions ***as*** an adjective.  Its use in sentence construction is essentially identical to a "real" adjective.  And I've given up trying to remember what the "official" name is, as that changes every 10-20 years.

Comment: @HotLicks Nouns can be modified by adjectives but not by adverbs. Adjectives cannot be modified by nouns. Daytime is a noun, which means that running cannot be an adjective. QED. Please don't call things adjectives just because they modify nouns. This is not a "new" analysis. It's been around longer than you've been alive. It's just more advanced than a third-grader's model of grammar.

Comment: @tchrist  - "Daytime" modifies the noun "running lights".   It's **NOT** "daytime-running".  The entities we're talking about are "running lights".  "Daytime" tells you that they are activated in the daytime.  In "thin red post" "thin" does not modify "red".

Comment: @rustyx Could you please use a longer example where your noun phrase is just part of a complete sentence?

Comment: @tchrist done. hope it helps.

Comment: @WS2 - Ask a sailor what "running lights" means.

Comment: @HotLicks You are quite right. The OED confirms *each of a set of small lights located on the front, rear, or sides of a vehicle that remain illuminated while the vehicle is running*. It is clear that the term applies to ships, aeroplanes and road vehicles. My ignorance was due to the fact that in the UK, the ones on vehicles are usually called "side lights". I will delete my earlier comment. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daytime_running_lamp

Technically, it's a **lamp** (=lights) indicating a **state**, and that lamp is for usage **at daytime**.

'**Daytime**' acts as an *adjective* here, like 'night' does in the combination 'night bomber' where night can't be an object, since it's not about 'bombing the night', it's about *night usage*. That adjective applies to the combination '*running lights*' where **lights** is definitely a *noun*. Unlike 'daytime' the gerund '**running**' there functions like a **noun**, since the lights *don't run* and just indicate the car engine's state *name* called 'running'. That name could be *any noun phrase*. So the word in question is a gerund in function of a **noun**.

Answer (score 1):

A **running light** is an open-form noun, as per its entry in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/running%20light):

> : any of the lights carried by a vehicle (such as a ship or automobile) that indicate size, position, or course

*Running* simply forms one of the components of the noun.

It's the same type of open-form noun as *ice cream*.

The only adjective in the phrase is **daylight**.

---

Despite the fact that its origin most likely comes from lights that indicate something is "turned on" (running), and *running* would have at first have been used adjectivally, the components are now simply functioning as parts of a whole.

This is, again, similar to *ice cream*, which was initially known as ***iced*** *cream* until the adjectival *iced* became part of the single word—and the *d* was dropped due to common pronunciation. Or like *laser*, which originally stood for *light amplification by stimulated emission of radiation* but is now "just" recognized as a word in its own right.

---

In response to a comment, since it's a common noun (no pun intended), there is no need to use hyphenation—just as there is no need to hyphenate *chocolate ice cream*. The correlation between all three words is not something that would be commonly misunderstood.

Comment: They're lights **for** running, so just a noun-noun compound. It was never an adjective, no more than it was in *running shoes*. People get this wrong all the time. Attributive nouns aren't adjectives. Easily confused with the situation of running water or running gazelles, which are indeed adjectival uses. But not running shoes or running lights.

Comment: @tchrist I both do and don't agree with this analysis. A light may *be* flashing, but it's not used *for* flashing. Similarly an engine may *be* running, but it's not used *for* running. If something is turned on, it can be considered to be in operation—or running. In this sense, a running light is a light that is shining or active. *Running* is used to describe its current state. In that sense a household light that's been turned on could also be called a running light. However, a *running light* on a boat can be either on *or* off, so I agree that it's not actually adjectival in this use.

Comment: @tchrist (Assuming that we're talking about the compound noun as opposed to the simple noun, which I was in my answer.)

Comment: You can have *quickly running gazelles*, but you cannot have *quickly running shoes*; instead you can have *rented running shoes*. It seems to me that you can have *rented running lights* just fine, but not *quickly running lights*. Or at least if you did, it would now mean something completely different. Right? It's like with *climbing gyms*: those aren't going anywhere the way *climbing roses* are. :) I agree that *running lights* is a noun; I just don't think *running* was ever an adjective there because I think it's like gyms not roses.

Comment: @tchrist But you *can* have *dimly running lights* or *brightly running lights*. Just as you can have *loudly running engines*. So, your analogy is not quite correct. ;)

Comment: No, I think those are *dim running lights* for the case in question; otherwise it's not the compound "open" noun you're saying it is. I agree that *dimly running lights* can exist, but those aren't running lights; they're merely lights that are running dimly.

Comment: @tchrist It can be both. Just because the same words are being used doesn't mean that they are referencing the same thing. Semantics is contextual, not absolute. In the compound noun *running light*, *running* is not an adjective. But you *can* still combine the adjective *running* with the single noun *light*. It's up to context to determine if somebody is talking about a (running light) or a running (light). I've heard *dimly running light* before; I've never heard *dim running light*. In any case, this is tangential to the main point of my answer. We agree on the usage in this case.

Comment: Well, you're saying that *daylight* is an adjective. How can that possibly be? If you had daylight sensors, those sensors wouldn't **be** daylight, so that fails the predicate test for adjectives. And they could never be very daylight sensors either, so that fails the *very* test for adjectives and adverbs. And they can't be more daylight sensors than these other ones here, so that fails the comparative degree test for adjectives and adverbs. What syntactic test can you present supporting your hypothesis? Surely *daylight* can only be a noun here. Attributive nouns aren't adjectives.

Comment: Minor point:  The OP said "daytime", not "daylight".

Comment: If I understand correctly, "running" in this context is a part of a noun? (I *have* to classify it by itself, because I'm implementing a word-based part-of-speech tagger).

Comment: @rustyx Yes, that's correct. No matter how it's looked at, *running* is being used as a noun in this context.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navigation_light):

> A *navigation light*, also known as a **running or position light**, is
>   a source of illumination on a vessel, aircraft or spacecraft.
>   Navigation lights give information on a craft's position, heading, and
>   status. Their placement is mandated by international conventions or
>   civil authorities. Navigation lights are not intended to provide
>   illumination for the craft making the passage, only for other craft to
>   be aware of it.

On boats and aircraft these "running lights" are normally only lit at night, so similar lights adapted to daytime use on automobiles are qualified with "daytime".

The lights were called "running lights" because they were only required when the vessel (generally a steamboat) was "running", ie, underway.  The basic scheme and much of the nomenclature was adapted to aircraft when they became common enough to create a collision risk.

The automotive sense was no doubt "borrowed" from the nautical sense.  But the "daytime" qualifier was added, not because the lights were extinguished at night, but because they were lit during the day, in contrast to nautical lights.

(Yes, this "answer" doesn't directly answer the original question, but I hope it clears up some of the confusion around the terminology.  Downvoting it won't hurt me, but it will make this info unavailable to low-rep users here.)